# Tsung: Using iterator in loop

Tags: load-testing, tsung

I'm trying to create load testing scenario for `ejabberd` with `tsung`.

I want simulate thousands of XMPP events from thousands clients. According tsung's [manual](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc68) I can create repeated actions using `for` loop:

```
<for from="1" to="10" incr="1" var="counter">
  [...]
  <request> <http url="/page?id=%%_counter%%"></http> </request>
  [...]
</for>
```

But this example don't working for me:

```
alex@alex:~/.tsung$ tsung -f jabber.xml start
Starting Tsung
"Log directory is: /home/alex/.tsung/log/20130417-1404"
3306- fatal: {error,{validity_constraint_Name_Token,37}}
Config Error, aborting ! {fatal,{{error,{validity_constraint_Name_Token,37}},
                                 {file,"jabber.xml"},
                                 {line,10},
                                 {col,29}}}
```

Full config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="notice" version="1.5">
    <clients>
        <client host="localhost" use_controller_vm="true"></client>
    </clients>
    <!-- Server side setup -->
    <servers>
        <for from="1" to="1000" incr="1" var="counter">
            <server host="t%%_counter%%.testserver.org" port="5222" type="tcp"></server>
        </for>
    </servers>
    <load>
        <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
            <users interarrival="2" unit="second"></users>
        </arrivalphase>
    </load>
    <!-- JABBER parameters -->
    <!-- to synchronise users,  use a global acknoledgement -->
    <options>
        <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="100"></option>
        <option type="ts_jabber" name="userid_max" value="10000"></option>
        <option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="mydomain.org"></option>
        <option type="ts_jabber" name="username" value="user"></option>
        <option type="ts_jabber" name="passwd" value="pass"></option>
    </options>
    <sessions>
        <session probability="100" name="jabber-loadtest" type="ts_jabber">
            <request><jabber type="presence:broadcast" show="online" status="Status: online" ack="no_ack"/></request>
            <thinktime value="1"></thinktime>
            <request><jabber type="presence:broadcast" show="offline" status="Status: offline" ack="no_ack"/></request>
        </session>
    </sessions>
</tsung>
```

How can I use loops in `tsung` configuration file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use loops in `<servers>` section, loops are available in `<session>` only.